# Update Ubuntu 12.04.3 Lts Updated version

Tags: networking

Hello any one help me out I have using ubuntu 12.04.3 LTS in my laptop.IN my college we are using LAN connection to access internet.Through this LAN server providing squid proxy serve to access internet.But the main problem is every time it asking username and password to access internet in firefox or other browsers but we cannot access internet other than browsers Any way to access internet throughout the system to update system softwares

Comment: You need to talk to your system administrators.

Answer (score 0):

Go to **System settings -> Network -> Network proxy** and fill in the proxy settings and hit **Apply system wide**.